# Assigning C++ function pointers to member functions of the same object

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, this-pointer

How do I get the function pointer assignments (and maybe the rest) in test.calculate to work?

```
#include <iostream>

class test {

    int a;
    int b;

    int add (){
        return a + b;
    }

    int multiply (){
        return a*b;
    }

    public:
    int calculate (char operatr, int operand1, int operand2){
        int (*opPtr)() = NULL;

        a = operand1;
        b = operand2;

        if (operatr == '+')
            opPtr = this.*add;
        if (operatr == '*')
            opPtr = this.*multiply;

        return opPtr();
    }
};

int main(){
    test t;
    std::cout << t.calculate ('+', 2, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, `int (*opPtr)() = NULL;` isn't a pointer to a member function, its a pointer to a free function.  Declare a member function pointer like this:

`int (test::*opPtr)() = NULL;`

Second, you need to specify class scope when **taking** the address of a member function, like this:

```
if (operatr == '+') opPtr = &test::add;
if (operatr == '*') opPtr = &test::multiply;
```

Finally, to call through a member function pointer, there is special syntax:

```
return (this->*opPtr)();
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class test {

    int a;
    int b;

    int add (){
        return a + b;
    }

    int multiply (){
        return a*b;
    }

    public:
    int calculate (char operatr, int operand1, int operand2){
        int (test::*opPtr)() = NULL;

        a = operand1;
        b = operand2;

        if (operatr == '+') opPtr = &test::add;
        if (operatr == '*') opPtr = &test::multiply;

        return (this->*opPtr)();
    }
};

int main(){
    test t;
    std::cout << t.calculate ('+', 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Don't be *that guy*. Nobody likes that guy.

Answer (score 3):

Like this  `int (test::*opPtr)() = NULL;`. Refer http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1

Edit: Also use `if (operatr == '+') opPtr = &test::add;` instead of `[..] = this.add` and `return (this->(opPtr))();` instead of `return opPtr();`. In fact, use typedefs and macros like the FAQ says and probably member function paramaters instead of class members `a` and `b`.

Comment: True, but there are more problems than just this one.